# create a performancepoint predefined chart list to select users as they wish

Tags: sharepoint-2010, data-warehouse, performancepoint

I have requirement for a MSBI dashboard which have pre designed charts, scorecard so that user can customize there dashboard as they want by selecting them from library, can this be possible in sharepoint preformancepoint pls share some possible solution for this.
Sorry for my spellings.

Ishanesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort of do this with PerformancePoint.  Basically, with dashboard designer, you would put all charts on the page and then use filters, scorecard rows, or KPI properties to determine when each chart should be visible and what data should be shown.

So you can make a scorecard and then when the user clicks on a particular row, the graphs related to that row will appear.  You can use KPI properties to filter the graphs as appropriate.

You could also try adding filters to your dashboard that allow the user to choose values that directly correlate to which charts are shown. There is no flexibility, however, for the user to choose the placement of the charts. You are basically throwing them all in the dashboard, setting the height and width properties, and letting them render. So you have to place the charts in such a way that they will look ok no matter which graphs the user chooses.

If you want something more than this, you could try making some custom web parts that show the charts based on a SharePoint filter rather than PerformancePoint filters.  The custom web parts would have contain code to pull from the PPS charts or SSRS charts and place them appropriately on the page.